# Whats the difference between jquery-1.3.2-vsdoc.js & jquery-1.3.2.min-vsdoc.js

Tags: .net, asp.net, jquery

What is the difference between those 2 files? Like I know they are for intellisense for Visual Studios so why would need 2 versions of it?

Like is the difference between jquery and jquery minified  just they remove the comments out and spacing?

So why would you need a special one for intellisense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a difference in the contents of the files?

I think the names may have to match the js file name (with vsdoc added)

Comment: I do believe it is just for file name matching.  Check here: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/21/jquery-intellisense-in-vs-2008.aspx

Comment: Hmm maybe but if you use a external script for you javascript I don' think it matters.

Answer (score 2):

The .min version is the [minified](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/jsmin.html) version of jQuery. I honestly don't know why you need a minified AND vsdoc version in your app though... Maybe if you just want the smallest file possible in for development? For deploying you should use the normal .min file (the one that is minified but **not** the vsdoc).